# security model of Linux password entry

Tags: security, password, gui, user-interface

Whenever a Windows application wants to do something requiring administrator privileges, my screen goes black and a prompt comes up, asking if I want to grant administrator privileges. I understand this security model: it relies on the user having control over the keyboard and mouse. Privileges go to whoever has control of input. If an application gains control of input while the security prompt is up, then it gains control of administrator privileges, even if it doesn't know my password.

In contrast, on Linux, the sudo command is the equivalent. When an application requests privileges, it prompts me to enter in my password. Thus, stealing input is insufficient to gain full privileges; an application must steal my password instead. However, I do not understand this model. It seems that this model just makes it easy to steal my credentials, because I am giving out my password constantly. What's stopping a malicious application from putting up a fake prompt and stealing my password, thus gaining privileges forever?

1. Is a security prompt bound in some way to the application that requests it?
2. If an application is able to impersonate a security prompt, or raise a security prompt while pretending to be another application, then is it assumed that the application already has full control of the computer and cannot raise its privileges by learning my password?
3. If I trust an application once, then is it ok for that application to steal my password?
4. Does Linux (theoretically) prevent non-root keyloggers, or can a non-root keylogger sniff my password even when I'm typing it into a legitimate security prompt?

I do not understand what stops a malicious unprivileged program from wrenching privileges from an administrator account. The security model could simply be that all programs run by an administrator are assumed to have access to root if they wish for it, and that administrators cannot rely on root/non-root being a meaningful barrier. Windows runs under this premise in practice. I can't tell if Linux tries to make any additional guarantees.

Comment: Gnome uses this a lot. Just try to add a printer without being an admin (root or lpadmin).

Comment: @JodkaLemon I guess the (essentially pathetic) screen locks do this too, in fact.   The user password doesn't seem so bad -- if an application can ask you for that, it can already do whatever it wants to you anyway.    **However,** I've seen some GUI locks that will notice if the system was suspended outside of your X session (e.g. from a VT console), then say because of such you *do* now need the root password to unlock...something I should never have fallen for  ever...probably my laptop is crawling with evil geniuses...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read with Wayland there comes the infrastructure to prohibit it, but now it's still a problem.

Just see

```
xinput test-xi2
```

The first article I read about the problem:

http://theinvisiblethings.blogspot.de/2011/04/linux-security-circus-on-gui-isolation.html

Further and deeper discussion:

http://lwn.net/Articles/517375/

Comment: This is a significant issue but it seems a little bit to the side of what is being asked about, namely, applications asking you *directly* for a password ("a malicious application from putting up a fake prompt").

Comment: Was more of an answer to point four and I think this leaves the other asked problems way behind it regarding security implications.

Comment: I agree that if an unprivileged program is able to keylog other programs, then impersonation is a moot point. Pretending to be someone else is pointless when you can just steal information directly from the user.